# You must enter certificate nickname as ssl3 and/or tls is enabled?

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish-6

I'm using glassfish 6 with java 11. So initially in https listener 2 i have TLS turned on, and when I try to turn SSL3 it says "you must enter certificate nickname as ssl3 and/or tls is enabled glassfish"; but i already gave it the name "s1sa", my cacerts and keystore have a valid cert with that name, i have the same password as master but still not working.

Im thinking this could be a bug in glassfish, am i doing something wrong?

I tried: changing the name of certificate , setting the master password to the one in the keystore and cacerts. Also tried turning off "TLS" (now i can't turn it on either, it says the same message), tried editing domains.xml and replace s1as name. Log doesn't say anything related either.

I was expecting to see TLS and or SSL3 enabled whenever i click on the checkbox.

The whole problem started because uploads to a servlet in the "https" protocol are 10 times slower, so i'm guessing everything is connected